# C-x C-f causes python shell to start in python-mode

Tags: python

I normally use C-x C-f to counsel-find-file by every time I try using it in python-mode, it starts up the Python Shell in a buffer. I've tried investigating whether there is a hotkey conflict using "C-h b", but all that comes up when I search through "C-h b" for "C-x C-f" is:

```
C-x C-f        counsel-find-file
C-x C-k C-f    kmacro-set-format
C-x 4 C-f      find-file-other-window
C-x 5 C-f      find-file-other-frame
```

Can anyone help me figure out why C-x C-f is starting up the Python shell in python mode?

Comment: What does `C-h c C-x C-f` show? Also, press `C-h l` immediately after `C-x C-f`. What's on the line with `C-x C-f`?

Comment: For the first I get "C-x C-f runs the command counsel-find-file". For the second, when I press C-x C-f it opens a python shell and simultaneously runs counsel-find-file, so I can't type "C-h l" while in the minibuffer. If I only have 1 buffer open with source code, [this](https://imgur.com/R28XH1B) is what I see immediately after doing C-x C-f.

Comment: You can press `C-h l` at any time. Please do this after the problematic `C-x C-f` and copy-paste the last few lines from the `*Help*` buffer.

Comment: Ah, I see. `C-h l` was overriden by counsel-load-library. But I was able to `M-x view-lossage`. Unfortunately doesn't seem to mention python shell
`<ns-open-file-line> [ns-open-file-select-line]`

`<down-mouse-1> [mouse-drag-region]`

`<mouse-1> [mouse-set-point]`

 `C-x C-f [counsel-find-file]`

 `C-g [minibuffer-keyboard-quit]`

 `M-x [counsel-M-x]`

 `...`

`<return> [ivy-done]`

Comment: Wow, overriding help bindings is evil. So it seems that starting the Python shell is not due to a binding. Hmmm. Do you know the name of a function that's involved in starting or displaying the Python shell? If so you can set it to [debug on entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Debugging.html) and look at the backtrace. E.g. `M-x debug-on-entry RET python-shell-get-buffer RET`.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the function that started the shell, but I think I've isolated the part of my init.el file that was causing the problem. I was using the "small config example" verbatim from [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), and when I commented that block out the problem went away. It specifically seems to do with `counsel-find-file`, which sucks because I really like that function, oh well. Anyway thanks for the advice, I'm definitely gonna try and clean up my keybindings, they're all over the place.